# How do I center div in browser without using position:fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to be centered in the user's browser.  However, I can't use the "position: fixed" css code because if I shrink the browser, no scroll bar appears allowing the user scroll the browser to see the entire div.

Additionally, if I use "position:fixed" and the user's screen is too small, part of the div can't be seen in the user's browser.  There also is no way for the user to scroll to see it.

So I need to either allow the user to scroll around and see the entire div OR figure out a way to center the div without using "position: fixed".

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried `margin: auto;`

Comment: @Darshan That will only work if you also set the width of the div to something less than 100%, which will generally lead to a value being used that doesn't work well for responsive web design.

Comment: i actually ended up using margin auto because i need my website to work with ie8, which doesn't allow flex boxes.  if there are other ways to make it work, that would be great.  for people with websites that work on ie8 and newer browsers, do they have multiple versions of code - one for older and one for newer browsers?

Answer (score 2):

This should be done using flexbox:

```css
.flex-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
     -moz-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -moz-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem; /* optional */
  border: 1px solid red; /* not needed */
}

.flex-center {
  padding: 3rem; /* optional */
  background-color: #787878; /* not needed */
  color: white; /* not needed */
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* not needed */
  padding: 0; /* not needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-center">I am centered</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-center"><p>I am also centered, but I have a lot more content and I should be taller than the deivice width.</p>
    <p>Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, missing until dinner time, and need to chase tail and slap owner's face at 5am until human fills food dish. Play time. You call this cat food? attack feet refuse to drink water except out of someone's glass and groom yourself 4 hours - checked, have your beauty sleep 18 hours - checked, be fabulous for the rest of the day - checked!. Put toy mouse in food bowl run out of litter box at full speed . Eat owner's food kitten is playing with dead mouse so chase mice, but see owner, run in terror for stare out the window yet chase after silly colored fish toys around the house scream at teh bath. Cat not kitten around see owner, run in terror scream at teh bath. Lick the plastic bag scratch leg; meow for can opener to feed me or sniff other cat's butt and hang jaw half open thereafter asdflkjaertvlkjasntvkjn (sits on keyboard), but kitty scratches couch bad kitty for stare at the wall, play with food and get confused by dust flop over. Destroy couch as revenge howl uncontrollably for no reason and lounge in doorway hola te quiero and pelt around the house and up and down stairs chasing phantoms cat is love, cat is life. Scamper meow loudly just to annoy owners for friends are not food but rub face on owner yet unwrap toilet paper. Put toy mouse in food bowl run out of litter box at full speed . Hide at bottom of staircase to trip human. Lick arm hair wake up human for food at 4am for eat all the power cords, hide at bottom of staircase to trip human or catch mouse and gave it as a present. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Un-prefixed CSS version (also removed cosmetic rules):

```
.flex-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem; /* optional */
}

.flex-center {
  padding: 3rem; /* optional */
}
```

Comment: That is super overkill.

Comment: Not if OP means vertically centered when they say "centered in the user's browser". If they don't mean vertically centered, all they need to do is remove the `min-height` and my solution still works.

Comment: And if they want vertical alignment they can set the position, using "absolute" or "relative" much simpler than flexbox.

Comment: Firstly, a solution doesn't have to be simple. It has to do the job properly. Secondly, how does `position` align vertically? You made me curious.

Comment: *"a solution doesn't have to be simple"* No. But, when it can be, it's entirely better than one that isn't. Especially since Flexbox isn't even a standard yet. See my second code snippet for a solution that handles horizontal and vertical alignment using standards.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property you are really looking for is 'margin', you must set to auto to get something centered:

```
#div
{
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: So if i do `text-align: auto;` it gets centered? :D

Comment: That will not only work if you also set the width of the div to something less than 100%

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <section id="parent">
    <div></div>
 </section>
```

You can either use flexbox style:

```
#parent {
    height: /* you set the height */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

div {
    width: /* you set the width */
    height: /* you set the height */
}
```

Or use absolute positioning for the div and set the position of parent to relative:

```
#parent {
    width: /* you set the width */
    height: /* you set the height */
    position: relative;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    width: /* you set the width */
    height: /* you set the height */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Place the div inside a parent container.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is place the div inside of a wrapper element that has `text-align:center` applied to it. Then, on the div that needs to be centered, just set `{ display:inline-block; }` which does two things.

1. It will allow the child `div` to adjust its width from the normal `100%`
   to the smallest size possible without hiding any of the content.
2. It will allow the child `div` to respond to the inherited
   `text-align:center` instruction.

```css
#parent { 
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid black; /* Border added just to show position */
}
#child { 
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red; /* Border added just to show position */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
     I'm the child &lt;div&gt;
  </div>
</div>
```

And, if you also need vertical alignment, you just need to leverage the `display` property to use `relative` and `absolute` (which will not cause the problems that `fixed` does) and use the **[CSS3 `transform` and `translate` properties](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)**:

```css
html, body { height:100%; }
#parent {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative; 
  border:1px solid black;
}

#parent div {
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* Vertical-Align */
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  /* CSS transform translate can easily align things */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) ;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>Centered!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't use this vertical centering technique anymore because it has a major flaw: you need to know the child's height so you can set the parent taller. If the child's height is bigger than the hard-coded height of the parent, it will overflow the parent and cover elements below and above it. Also, if the parent happens to be the body, you'll lose the ability to see the overflown content. That's why I use flex, even if it seems more complicated. I think it's better.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You won't have any height issues if you use `height:100%;`. My example just scales that down. Iv'e adjusted it to show that this is a non-issue. As you can see, the child's height is not set anywhere. Flexbox will one day be great, but as it is not standard yet and there are differences in implementations and results as of now, it is not a great solution.

Comment: [Is it](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/337dsj5s/)? Your exact solution, with content inside the centered element.

Comment: LOL! Yes, it is! Especially since you pasted non-CSS into the CSS frame which caused none of the CSS to work! Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/gnLm27Ld/2/

Comment: I fixed it, refresh. Your fiddle also has the issue I'm describing. Sorry for the previous mistake. I rushed.

Comment: I don't see any issue. Expand the "result" window to be as tall as you can and you'll see the vertical alignment. And, when the window isn't big enough, you get scrolling behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131946/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-scott-marcus).